# how to read a particular xelement in the list using c# code

Tags: c#

I have the below xelement collection which I want to filter by ows_LinkTitle and retrieve a particular xelement using c# code.

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:FDC6E3F0-6GH3-11d1-A2A3-00BB00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:D2F41010-65C3"
  xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"        
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <rs:data ItemCount="71">
     <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="DocumentUrl1" />
     <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="DocumentUrl2" />
     <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="DocumentUrl3" />
    </rs:data>
 </listitems>
```

I tried the below code but it gives me the error:

```
 The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

XElement updateItem = (from xml2 in listItems.Descendants("rs:data")
                            where xml2.Element("ows_LinkTitle").Value == strListItemName
                            select xml2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **pay attention** to the XML namespaces in play, and you cannot just use the namespace prefixes in your XPath expressions! You need to explicitly define `XNamespace` entities for those, and use those XML namespaces in your XPath expressions.

Try something like this:

```
string inputXml = @"<listitems xmlns:s='uuid:FDC6E3F0-6GH3-11d1-A2A3-00BB00C14882' 
                                           xmlns:dt='uuid:D2F41010-65C3'
                                           xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'        
                                           xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
                                <rs:data ItemCount='71'>
                                    <z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='DocumentUrl1' />
                                    <z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='DocumentUrl2' />
                                    <z:row ows_Attachments='0' ows_LinkTitle='DocumentUrl3' />
                                </rs:data>
                                </listitems>";

// get the XDocument    
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(inputXml);

// define the relevant XML namespaces to be used 
XNamespace rs = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset";
XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";


// get the list of <rs:data>/<z:row> elements
var dataItems = xdoc.Descendants(rs + "data").Elements(z + "row");

// get the one entry you need - you need to compare the value
// of the "ows_LinkTitle" *attribute* (not element) to your search term
var item = dataItems.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Attribute("ows_LinkTitle").Value == strListItemName);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to reference the elements via a namespace, e.g. using [`XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
XNanespace rs = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset";
listItems.Descendants(rs + "data")
.. same for other elements with namespaces
```

Also, note that `ows_LinkTitle` is an attribute of `z:row`, not an element.

Comment: And also, `ows_LinkTitle` is an attribute on the `<z:row>` node - not the `<rs:data>` nodes the OP is querying against....